# Group Priority on a Subset of Nodes

Tags: scheduler, torque

I am using a recent build of Torque/Maui (w/ PBS) to schedule jobs on a cluster with heterogenous hardware.  Hardware consists on two set of 10 nodes for which I would like to have two group have elevated priority on one of the sets of nodes. For example:

```
Node set A of 10 nodes has elevated priority for User Group 1
Node set B of 10 nodes has elevated priority for User Group 2
```

I am familiar with how this is accomplished for all nodes, which is documented here:

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/maui/5.1.3priorityusage.php

However, I am unfamiliar on the best strategy to set this type of priority on a subset of the cluster. From what I can ascertain from the Maui docs it may be done using node sets or partitions, but I am unsure if either of these are correct or there is another strategy all together.

Edit: I would prefer to have a single queue as it simplifies usability and would enable a user to potentially use the entire cluster, albeit with differing priority on node set A and B.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand the question, you've confused node allocation with job priority. Job priority determines how much more quickly Maui will run a job, as it accrues priority in the priority reservation queue. This will determine how soon a job can run, within the constraints placed on the job, relative to all other jobs in the eligible/idle queue.

That's separate from where Maui decides to place (schedule) jobs. The most natural way to handle this type of use case is with standing reservations. You can create reservations over each set of nodes (via host list, feature, or partition), and then give both groups (or everyone) access to both reservations, but apply negative affinity to everyone outside the group with preferential access.

Example:

```
SRCFG[rsvA] NODEFEATURES=setA
SRCFG[rsvA] GROUPLIST=group1,ALL-
SRCFG[rsvA] HOSTLIST=ALL

SRCFG[rsvB] NODEFEATURES=setB
SRCFG[rsvB] GROUPLIST=group2,ALL-
SRCFG[rsvB] HOSTLIST=ALL
```

With this configuration, Maui will create reservation rsvA to include only the nodes with the "setA" property/feature, and jobs from group1 will gravitate (i.e., have positive affinity) to the nodes in that reservation. Likewise, jobs from users in group2 will flow to the nodes in rsvB, with the "setB" property (as defined in the nodes file, or on NODECFG lines in the maui.cfg). This configuration works fine with a single queue, and is essentially user-transparent.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is quite close to what I want to accomplish. What would happen if there was many jobs waiting in  Q state from Group 1 then user from Group 2 submits jobs? Would these Group 2 jobs get priority to run on Set B, or due to longer queue time, would obs from Group 1 would be run prior to jobs from Group 2? Basically, I have two sets of hardware, each owned by their respective group. The have agreed to share resources, but prefer to have priority on their own hardware i.e. their jobs are *always* at top of queue with respect to other group(s).

Comment: To my knowledge, Maui cannot do this directly, at least not without some special hoop-jumping. Moab can do it with the "HPEnable" cred modifier.

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/9-0-1/MWM/help.htm#topics/moabWorkloadManager/topics/resourceAccess/managingreservations.html#aclmodifiers

Comment: `SRCFG[johnspace] USERLIST=john CLASSLIST=~debug`


"All of user john's jobs are allowed to run in the reservation at any time. Debug jobs are also allowed to run in this reservation but are only considered after all of John's jobs are given an opportunity to start. User john's jobs are considered before debug jobs regardless of job priority."

Comment: Another possibility is to add preemption to the mix: Group 1 jobs running on Set B resources get marked as preemptees, and when Group 2 jobs marked as preemptors come along, they bump (cancel/requeue) Group 1 jobs. I'm not inclined to suggest a configuration for this, because A) it can get messy, depending on the use case, and B) most versions of Torque and Maui have bugs in the code related to this functionality. The simpler your configuration, the more likely it will give you successful results.

Comment: So will this work: (1) create two classes (queues) for each node set, queueA and queueB, (2) create reservation same node sets, rsvA and rsvB, as you specified above `SRCFG[rsvA] NODEFEATURES=setA` and `SRCFG[rsvB] NODEFEATURES=setB`(3) then do something like: `SRCFG[rsvA] GROUPLIST=group1 CLASSLIST=~queueB` and `SRCFG[rsvB] GROUPLIST=group2 CLASSLIST=~queueA`.  Would this basically allow group1 to run on rsvA, and also allow jobs from queueB to run only after jobs from group1 are running?

Comment: Yes, that should work for what you want (using Moab), provided you restrict group1 from queueB, and group2 from queueA...but test it and let us know! Keep in mind that configuration will not directly address secondary group jobs already running in the reservation/s. For that, preemption might be an ideal solution, if it works; or, something like setting resources_max.walltime on the queues to at least keep jobs from occupying resources for an excessive amount of time.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify I will try this on Maui, not Moab.

Comment: Yesterday, I said I don't think Maui supports HPEnable, only Moab: "...Maui cannot do this directly, at least not without some special hoop-jumping. Moab can do it with the "HPEnable" cred modifier." So I don't think you can do exactly what you're wanting with Maui. If users in a secondary group are willing to have their jobs get requeued, you might try something like QOS-based preemption, with the default requeue preemptpolicy, and then give users the option to specify a QOS with the preemptee flag at submission time. The primary group queues would have to set the preemptor flags.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that the tilde is the HPEnable modifier. I will mark your answer as accepted and continue to mull this over. Clearly this will not be easy using Maui!

Comment: For future reference, as a workaround, it may be easier to throttle `GROUPCFG[badgroup]  MAXPROC[CLASS:nottheirqueue]=2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113061/discussion-between-vince-and-clusterdude).